# How to update old Expo app to latest SDK for iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I've inherited an Expo app built for iOS and Android using SDK v34. I'm a developer for many programming languages, but not javascript (yet). I've already experimented with getting the Expo app to run, and found that it will run with Node v9. However, it won't work with the latest Expo Go app (supporting SDK v46+).

What is the correct process to fully update this Expo app to the latest everything (assuming there are no breaking changes that need to be manually handled)? I assumed it was this, but it didn't work for me:

1. `npm install` - Success
2. `npx expo start` - Success. Starts without error
3. `npx expo upgrade` - Success
4. `npx expo start` - Failure. Throws a JS error

Is this the right procedure? There is also a folder called `ios` and `android`. The instructions that print out after each `npx expo start` say to change into the `ios` folder and run `pod install` in your iOS directory and then re-build your native projects to compile the updated dependencies. I don't know what it means to "re-build your native projects to compile the updated dependencies".

Some help and guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the error message?